# File descriptor limits in /etc/system vs /etc/sysctl.conf vs /etc/security/limits.conf on Solaris

Tags: solaris, limit, file-descriptors, ulimit, sysctl

Let me explain first what I understood.

In Solaris 10, `rlim_fd_max` and `rlim_fd_cur` in `/etc/system` set the hard and soft limits at the system level.

And `/etc/security/limits.conf` sets the limits for `login`, right?  So for a user it overwrites the limits set by `/etc/system`.  If limits are not set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, the user will have the values in `/etc/system` right?

So, what is `/etc/sysctl.conf` for?

On my Solaris 10, I don't have either `sysctl.conf`, or `limits.conf`.  In this case how can I set limits on individual user that are persisted after reboot?  Any other mechanism than setting them in `profile`?

Comment: `sysctl.conf` is for Linux, not Solaris.  Did you see a reference to it being used on Solaris somewhere?

Comment: @alanc yes, in oracle documentation about tuning, it is mentioned.

Comment: It is mentioned for Solaris or for Linux?  I only see it in reference to Linux platforms.

Comment: Oh yes..i always do miss these side headings..thank you..and anyhow its everything clear now!

Answer (score 1):

Parameters `rlim_fd_cur` and `rlim_fd_max` in `/etc/system` are no longer recommended with Solaris 10 and forward. It should be used the resource control `process.max-file-descriptor` instead, which replaces the replaces the System V interprocess communication. The adventaje is that server reboot is no longer necessary and you can use *projects* withouth affecting other processes.

Then to change the hard limit for the project `user.root` it is necessary to also set the privilege level priv (the hard limit) like the following command:

```
# projmod -s -K "process.max-file-descriptor=(priv,4096,deny)" user.root
```

To change the soft limit for project `user.other` it is necessary to also set the privilege level like:

```
$ projmod -s -K "process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,1024,deny)" user.other
```

Projects can be found in the `/etc/project` file.

This is an example of `projadd` (to create) and `projmod` (to set):

```
# useradd test
# projadd -c "Test" 'user.test'
# projmod -s -K "project.max-shm-memory=(privileged,6GB,deny)" 'user.test'
# projmod -s -K "process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,1024,deny)" user.test
# cat /etc/project|grep -i test
user.test:101:Test:::process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,1024,deny);project.max-shm-memory=(privileged,6442450944,deny)
#
```

`projadd` and `projmod` are persistent values. For non-persistent values you should use `prctl` command.

Example:

```
# prctl -n project.max-shm-memory -v 8gb -r -i project default 
# prctl -n project.max-shm-memory -i project default 
project: 3: default 
NAME PRIVILEGE VALUE FLAG ACTION RECIPIENT 
project.max-shm-memory 
usage 8.49MB 
privileged 8.00GB - deny - 
system 16.0EB max deny -
```

`/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.conf` are Linux files.

`limits.conf` sets limits on the system resources in a user-session in the `pam_limits` PAM module. --> This is similar to `projmod`.

`sysctl.conf` is the file that `sysctl` uses to modify kernel parameters at runtime. --> This is similar to modify the `/etc/system`.

If the user has not restrictions on `limits.conf` the default values are taken from:
Kernel: `init` process
Inherited: parent process (vendors configurations are in `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/`)
PAM: `limits.conf` (can replace Kernel and Inherited )
Process by itself (can replace PAM, Kernel and Inherited, "`getrlimit`, `setrlimit`, `prlimit` - get/set resource limits").

Changes in `limits.conf` and `sysctl.conf` are persistent.

To set limits for an individual user you must edit `limits.conf` file.
Like:

```
{account} soft as size (KB)
{account} hard as size (KB)
```

Example:

```
oracle soft nproc 2047
oracle hard nproc 16384
oracle soft nofile 1024
oracle hard nofile 65536
```

Reboot is not necessary for limits.conf modification, but the new parameters will apply just to the new sessions.

If you want modify a running process you should use `prlimit`.
Like:

```
prlimit --pid <pid> --<limit>=<soft>:<hard>
```

Example:

```
prlimit --pid 12345 --nofile=1024:2048
```